# Yii TbTabs widget with render partials what happened with $_post request

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, http-post, renderpartial

I'm using tbTabs, but when submit,  only the first tab _audio view get $_post  request. what happened with other render partials view's $_post data?

> create.php

Contain

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
    'tabs'=>array(
        array(
            'id'=>'tab1',
            'active'=>true,
            'label'=>'audio',
            'content'=>$this->renderPartial("_audio", array('model' => $model),true),            
        ),
        array(
            'id'=>'tab2',
            'active'=>false,
            'label'=>'videos',
            'content'=>$this->renderPartial("_videos", array('model' => $model),true),
        ),

        array(
            'id'=>'tab3',
            'active'=>false,
            'label'=>'games',
            'content'=>$this->renderPartial("_games", array('model' => $model),true),

        ),        
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are three separate forms in the tabs, they are independent of each other.

You will need to use JavaScript/jQuery to post the three forms via AJAX, before refreshing/redirecting the page.